# SQL Query to get items that have only one value

Tags: sql, excel

I am looking for a SQL Query to select all values with ACTIVITY value of 'SPORT' and not duplicate NAME value.

Table:

```
 ID    NAME      ACTIVITY
 1      Sam       Sport
 2      Sam       Music
 3      Alex      Sport
 4      Peter     Reading
 5      Rex       Painting
```

Example: Search on Name with only one activity (SPORT). 
Results must be like this:

```
3     Alex     SPORT
```

Note: SAM is not in the results as he has two activity name of SPORT and Music, but Alex has only one activity of Sport.
I'm using excel.

I have tried this code, but it returns Sam and Alex.

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Activity]
FROM [TABLE$]
WHERE [ACTIVITY] = 'SPORT'
GROUP BY [ID], [NAME], [Activity]
HAVING COUNT ([Name]) = 1))
```

Comment: What's the database? Excel connects to an underlying database.

Comment: Please show you have done some research or thinking of your own. What have you tried? This looks like a homework question.

Comment: I have tried this code, but it returns Sam and Alex.                                     
 strsql = SELECT [ID], [Name], [Activity] 
                    FROM [TABLE$] 
                    WHERE [ACTIVITY] = 'SPORT' 
                    GROUP BY [ID], [NAME], [Activity] 
                    HAVING COUNT ([Name]) = 1))

Comment: Awesome! It works perfectly.                                                                          
But another question. What should I do, to add another condition to select Activities with values of 'Sport' and 'Music' for any Name that only have two activities?  Results should be 'Sam'. He has only 2 activities of 'sport' and 'music'. Thx, Vahid

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the column `[ID]` in the results then:

```
SELECT [Name], MAX([Activity]) 
FROM [TABLE$]  
GROUP BY [NAME] 
HAVING MIN([ACTIVITY]) = 'SPORT' AND MAX([ACTIVITY]) = 'SPORT'
```

If you want the full row:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM [TABLE$] AS t
WHERE t.[ACTIVITY] = 'SPORT' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [TABLE$]
  WHERE [NAME] = t.[NAME] AND [ACTIVITY] <> t.[ACTIVITY]
)
```